# Как разделить гигантское число на python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, длинная-арифметика, int

Работаю с большими числами, необходимо разделить `int` типа этого

```
4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300
```

на 17

получаю ошибку:

```bsh
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

Целочисленное деление тоже ведёт к этой ошибке.

Как на питоне разделить такое число? (на результате достаточно целого числа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С делением через `/`, действительно, эта ошибка повторяется, но не потому, что он не может делить, а потому, что исходное делимое слишком велико для помещения в double (даже с неизбежной погрешностью), а при `/` оба числа конвертируются в double (в Python - `float`) перед собственно делением. Вызвать `float()` на него тоже даёт ту же ошибку.

С делением нацело - знак `//` - проблем нет, результат возвращается и корректный:

```
>>> 4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300//3
1619483545396571141194031987498067348193800195994414849827697695020644901569603309483548256621841454949999082341638373036803868579725802618973251442190618480685736815245294560609941251379878112741733150730550428116110968377064399984500804586255079754958204464968956710187431937739827037895113178521763616674625030952297564851991427182128836910016368907686311195350848032221450421783121214652375188565312271728111619201755646720417088983807183513184839717928485841918863580180052643000588655988493354809276377162849419971573749502117562210158766
```

Если у вас деление нацело тоже не работает - возможно, у вас как-то очень странно скомпилирован сам Python. В таком случае, вам следует рассмотреть смену версии и/или поставщика.

Я проверял оба случая на Python 3.6 под Ubuntu 18.04/x86_64 и Python 3.7 на FreeBSD/i386, так что обычные проблемы 32/64 явно не влияют. Windows под рукой нет, может быть, её странности недостаточно отражены в коде интерпретатора (например, то, что long в 64-битном режиме - 32 бита, противоречит не только устоявшимся традициям всех остальных, но и собственной же .NET).

P.S. Тут есть вопрос, который, возможно, требует жалобы на баг:

```
>>> float(4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
>>> float('1e+308')
1e+308
>>> float('1e+309')
inf
>>> float('4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300')
inf
```

такое неровное поведение требует как минимум обсуждения его целесообразности.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [оператор целочисленного деления](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division)

```
x // 3
```

Или [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

```
Decimal(x) / Decimal(3)
```

Comment: целочисленное не работает, та же ошибка, что и с простым делением

Comment: https://ideone.com/2En3MO